# What's the meaning of "set himself to"?

Tags: phrases, verbs, phrasal-verbs

“When I saw him that afternoon so enwrapped in the music at St. James's Hall I felt that an evil time might be coming upon those whom **he had set himself to** hunt down.”

I have found these sentence in a Sherlock Holmes short story. What does "set someone to do" mean?

Thank you all.
Cheers,
Andrea

Comment: He had *set himself **the task** of hunting them down.*

Comment: Look at the meaning of Set 2.3 https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/set

Comment: ... Perhaps between 2.1  / 2.2 / 2.3, used reflexively. _set oneself to_ = _resolve to_.

Comment: *set someone to do* means *give someone a task or target*. See #4 (last example): *I've set myself to finish the job by the end of the month.* at https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/set_1

Comment: You may also think of it as *putting* oneself to the task. Making a distinct choice of taking on the task yourself.